# Why docker filebeat exited with code 0?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-compose, logstash-forwarder

Iam using docker-elk in github and running the docker-elk container.my logs are showing in kibana.
Now i want to use file beat instead of logstash-forwarder in docker-elk.for that i selected elastic/beats in github and built a docker image.Now this is included in my docker-compose.yml.now 
when iam running the container logstash running,elastic search running but file beat exited with code 0.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
logstash:
  image: logstash:2.0
  command: logstash agent --config /etc/logstash/conf.d/ -l /var/log/logstash/logstash.log --debug
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    - ./logstash/patterns/nginx:/etc/logstash/patterns/nginx

  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
kibana:
  build: kibana/
  volumes:
    - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
beats:
  image: pavankuamr/beats

  volumes:
   - ./logstash/beats:/etc/filebeat
   - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
  links:
   - logstash
   - elasticsearch
  environment:
   - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
   - LS_HOST=logstash
   - LS_TCP_PORT=5044
```

This is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat:

  prospectors:

      paths:
        - /var/log/nginx/access.log



      input_type: log


   registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry


   config_dir: /etc/filebeat/conf.d



  elasticsearch:
    enabled: false

    hosts: ["localhost:9200"]




   logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts
    enabled: true
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

This is my logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
   port => 5044
   type => "logs"
  }
  file {
    type => "nginx"
    start_position => "beginning"
    path => [ "/var/log/nginx/access.log" ]
  }
 file {
    type => "nginxerror"
    start_position => "beginning"
    path => [ "/var/log/nginx/error.log" ]
  }
}
filter {

  if [type] == "nginx" {
    grok {
    patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
    match => { "message" => "%{NGINX_ACCESS}" }
    remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
    add_tag => ["nginx_access"]
    }

    geoip {
      source => "remote_addr"
    }
  }

  if [type] == "nginxerror" {
    grok {
    patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
    match => { "message" => "%{NGINX_ERROR}" }
    remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
    add_tag => ["nginx_error"]
    }

  }
}


output {
    elasticsearch {

        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                sniffing => true
                manage_template => false
                index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }

}
```

Comment: First the elasticsearch output config has to be removed completely as the "enabled" options was removed in the recent releases. Is it possible that the log file does not exist when Filebeat is started? There is currently an issue if no log file exists to crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `hosts: ["localhost:9200"]` for `hosts: ["logstash:9200"]` into logstash output on `filebeat.yml`